# Creating partitions through script in init.rc

Tags: boot, internal-sd

Context/Resume:

- I'm changing the android platform to create two partitions in a SD Card. I need to do this as early as possible. I'm currently trying in `init.rc`
- It would be nice to obfuscate the access to one of the partitions. If I could keep it hidden would be better

And...the long story:

I'm trying to create new partitions on an SD card in a
device, and I need to be done as early as possible.
 I thought that the init.rc should be the best location for this, so I
tried to add a script call to perform the task, but I'm unable to
create these partitions (or get the reason it fails).
 First of all, is this premise valid? Should I be able to do this?

I call the script by:

```
service myscript /system/bin/logwrapper /system/bin/myscript.sh
   disabled
   oneshot
```

at init-time.  And the content´s of the .sh file is

```
fdisk /dev/sdcard < mykeys.input
```

where "mykeys.input" is the sequence of commands used to perform the task
of creating the partitions.

Is this the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Why not format the SD card using a computer?

Comment: Hy. The hardware i have have a little twist. This card is hardwired in the device< i know i know...it sucks but i must work with what i got  >
ps: It´s actually soldered in the board.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it a Galaxy or Nexus S? My Vibrant has "internal SD" that isn't actually an SD card, but often referred to as such.  It's treated as if it were a card, though; downloads go there, for example. Anyways, just curious: Why are you trying to format it?

Comment: I need to create two partitions:
-One of them will be available to the user
-Another one will be used to store downloaded data from a custom store. It will have some specific permission, and may contain some restricted information ( the app will handle this )

Answer (score 1):

```
service myscript /system/bin/logwrapper /system/bin/myscript.sh
   disabled
   oneshot
```

If you declare the service as disabled, it wont run unless you later explicitly start it.

But do you really want to repartition the card every time you boot the system? I would think you would want to partition it once, and then perhaps mount the partitions in the init script.

Comment: Hy Chris. Thanks for the tip. Lame mistake, but still i could not execute the commands in the script. ( At least they had no effect at all ).
And, yes, i will make some logic to prevent the re-partitioning.
 If you have an advice to do this ( once ) in any other way i would appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: Is /dev/sdcard the correct device name?   What happens if you run the script commands manually, after boot - do they work then?   Also don't forget to format (make a filesystem)

Comment: Chris ,i´ll try this. But do you know if a should be able to access the fdisk in the script?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you need to specify the full path for the fdisk binary?  You seem to be doing so for everything else.  Another thing - some of the stuff that runs in init like adbd is statically linked; I haven't looked into if that is a requirement, or just a precaution to make debugging still work if the dynamic libraries aren't available in a broken install.

Comment: Answering our question: I have no permission to execute the script. The device is not rooted. I suppose that it will not be a problem when running it through init.rc.

Comment: If you can change the flash device, ie install a new init.rc, the device is effectively "more than rooted" - you can change init.rc to make ro.secure 0 to temporarily make the adb shell run as root, then change it back after the experiment.  You **ARE** changing the init.rc in the compressed ramdisk image in flash, right?  Because just remounting the ramdisk writable and changing it won't let you do anything that survives a reboot.

Comment: Oh, BTW, many versions of the adb shell use "permission denied" as a generic error message for everything, including not finding the file you've tried to run...

Comment: Chris, i think that i found the problem.
I will confirm that everything is ok and post the answer for those who may have the same problem.
Unfortunately i dont have enough reputation < for now, i hope > to vote you up, but i am really thankful for your help and is because of people like you that this a great place for developers.

Thanks!